# Coordinate transform with known camera pose pairs

Tags: geometry, 3d, coordinate-systems, rotations, computer-vision

Let's say that we have two $3D$ coordinate systems, $A$ and $B$. Now I want to get the coordinate transform matrix $T_{AB}$ such that for any points $p_A$ in $A$, we can get its coordinate in $B$ by $p_B=T_{AB}p_A$.

I have searched and checked ICP algorithm which can help with that. It needs at least $3$ point pairs in $A$ and $B$ to get $T_{AB}$, and actually the more the better.

But now I have different data. I have paired known camera poses $A$ and $B$. Suppose I have a camera $c$. I know its pose $T_{c_A}$ in $A$ and $T_{c_B}$ in $B$, respectively. How to solve $T_{AB}$ with $T_{c_A}$ and $T_{c_B}$?

And what's the least number of camera pairs I need to solve $T_{AB}$?

Comment: I used ChatPGT - To calculate the coordinate transform matrix TAB between two 3D coordinate systems A and B, you can use the following steps:

Define the origin and the three basis vectors of coordinate system A, denoted as OA, e1A, e2A, and e3A.
Define the origin and the three basis vectors of coordinate system B, denoted as OB, e1B, e2B, and e3B.
Express the origin of system A in system B using the three basis vectors of system B, as OA_B = x1 * e1B + x2 * e2B + x3 * e3B.

Comment: Express the three basis vectors of system A in system B using the three basis vectors of system B, as e1A_B = x4 * e1B + x5 * e2B + x6 * e3B, e2A_B = x7 * e1B + x8 * e2B + x9 * e3B, e3A_B = x10 * e1B + x11 * e2B + x12 * e3B
Use the previous result to form a matrix TAB such as

Comment: The matrix TAB=     |x4 x7 x10|
                 |x5 x8 x11|
     |x6 x9 x12|
Now you can express any point pA in system A in system B using the matrix TAB, as pA_B = TAB * pA
Please note that this is just one way to calculate the coordinate transform matrix TAB, and there may be other methods as well.

It's also important to note that this method assumes that the two coordinate systems are related by a pure translation and rotation transformation, and doesn't take into account any scaling or skew factors.

Comment: Does this helps?

Comment: @Moti Sorry I think the answer from ChatGPT is not related to my question, but anyway, thank you for your help.